# How can I replace HTC Sense?

Tags: htc-sense, home-screen

I saw not using HTC Sense as a power-saving tip on another question, but I just wanted to know what the easiest way to replace HTC Sense is and what it requires me to do?

Do I lose all my widgets too or will it mostly change the way my Home screen looks?

Edit: I don't need HTC Sense to disappear completely from my phone or need to root it. I'm just curious how I would go about replacing HTC Sense with another application launcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace HTC Sense completely you will have to root your phone and replace the ROM completely. Please see this post for more information: [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)

If on the other hand you're looking at replacing your homescreen/launcher then there are plenty of options.

- [LauncherPro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/launcherpro/com.fede.launcher)
- [ADW.Launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/adw-launcher/org.adw.launcher)
- [HelixLauncher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/helixlauncher/com.helixproject.launcher)
- plenty more...

I personally have LauncherPro and have upgraded to the Plus version. The Plus version has 90% of the widgets Sense UI has but is in my opinion far quicker, more stable and has way more features.

*NB: I don't believe any of these Launchers allow you to utilise the widgets from Sense UI.*

EDIT: Just to answer your comment. LauncherPro is an app you can download and install from the Android Market. Once installed clicking the Home button will prompt you to select which launcher you'd like to use (either LauncherPro or Sense UI). All you would do from there is check the "Default" checkbox and select LauncherPro.

Comment: I guess I was more looking into how do you effectively replace HTC Sense with for example LauncherPro. How does it work? But +1 anyway for the effort!

Comment: @Ivo Sorry about that... forgot about that bit. Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially those are what we call "home" replacements.  You have the stock android home, or HTC's custom Sense home (or [insert manufacturer's custom home here]) that come with your device. But you can go on the market and download another one like LauncherPro or Helixlauncher or ADW launcher.

Usually people use these for additional features the stock home doesn't have, such as more screens, more icons on the screens or app drawer, or advanced memory management, special widgets, etc. (LauncherPro).