# How do I use stock UI on HTC Desire HD?

Tags: htc-desire-hd, vanilla-ui

How do I disable HTC Sense on my HTC Desire HD without having to root my phone?

I looked at a guide for the regular Desire and attempted to follow that but it didn't work (was missing the ability to force close HTC Sense).

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/how-can-i-replace-htc-sense According to an answer on that question, it requires root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't :o(

You can install another home screen app from the market if you don't want to use the Sense home screen.

If you want to avoid Sense altogether, you will need to root your phone and flash a non-Sense ROM.

Comment: wow that's kind of annoying I was looking forward to having a stock android with decent hardware, thanks for the answer.