# Revert an Android phone to vanilla rom from Google

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-android

Can we install a vanilla ROM to a non-Nexus Android device?

I have an Android phone (version 2.3.6) and I don't like the ROM installed by the manufacturer. I want to revert it to a vanilla ROM like Nexus devices have. Is it possible, and if so could you provide a guide?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash a smartphone with vanilla Android ROM](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29394/16575); see also: [How to remove TouchWiz and revert to a vanilla Android UI?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15984/16575), [Can you install vanilla Android on any phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38074/16575); [How can I install vanilla Android on the Kindle Fire?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17482/16575)

Answer (score 1):

A real vanilla ROM is not possible because you need drivers for the hardware in your mobile. This drivers depend on the manufacturer.

The nearest thing you can get is a custom ROM like CyanogenMod.